# awk not recognizing exponential numbers correctly - my mistake?

Tags: awk

awk version:
GNU Awk 4.1.1, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.2-p3, GNU MP 6.0.0)

I have the following input (small example):

```
Lh8627_00055___transposase_3    c368296268f9d0100b8a65d2cd57aaf2    424 Pfam    PF01610 Transposase 297 404 1.8E-11 T   22-06-2017  IPR002560   Transposase IS204/IS1001/IS1096/IS1165, DDE domain      
Lh8627_05835___transposase_1    212014f87f94178312dac70f061d81c6    469 Pfam    PF06782 Uncharacterised protein family (UPF0236)    30  399 4.5E-37 T   22-06-2017  IPR009620   Uncharacterised protein family UPF0236      
Lh8627_03700___transposase_3    916962acc8271c66b217ab903d836768    401 Pfam    PF06782 Uncharacterised protein family (UPF0236)    201 334 4.4E-6  T   22-06-2017  IPR009620   Uncharacterised protein family UPF0236      
Lh8627_01850___transposase_1    05e46b0f13cf6aa7db8adcf5fd3fd39d    409 Pfam    PF01548 Transposase 8   160 3.0E-29 T   22-06-2017  IPR002525   Transposase, IS111A/IS1328/IS1533, N-terminal   GO:0003677|GO:0004803|GO:0006313
```

I would like to filter lines which have in the 9th column a value lower than 1.0E-10

My command is `awk '$9 < 1.0E-10' my file`. But it is not filtering the 3rd line in the small input above for example. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: with your input - they all should be filtered out. Otherwise, it's unclear whether it should consider only numbers and remove the lines with non-number (in 9th field) by default

Comment: Why? I would say `4.5E-37` is definitely smaller than  `1.0E-10`, right? Or is there another problem?

Comment: you wrote *the 9th column* - with awk default separator the 9th field values are ` 1.8E-11 T (UPF0236) ...`

Comment: It is a formatting problem. Column 9 is all floating point numbers with E notation! In the real input.

Comment: `4.5E-37` is not in 9th field

Comment: In the third line, the ninth field is “(UPF0236)”.

Comment: you are confusing your input with your description

Comment: No, it is just the problem that I copied this form console where tab gets converted to space. But if I check witch `cut -f 9` I get for those lines `1.8E-11, 4.5E-37, 4.4E-6, 3.0E-29`

Comment: try using `awk -F\t ` to only have tab as separator.

Comment: The source you posted has incorrect 9th field. May it be that the separator for each column is a tab (\t)?

Comment: The problem was that awk took not only tab as delimiter but space as well. Was not aware of. Thx Archemar

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I did not understand that awk also uses space as delimiter and not only tab. After adding `-F'\t'` it works.
The number comparison was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your command is good. However, your input is not: the 9th member in your example is not always the expected number:

```
$ awk '{print $9}' <your_file>
1.8E-11
(UPF0236)
(UPF0236)
3.0E-29
```

You could for example rearrange your input by removing unwanted elements using `sed`:

```
sed 's/protein family (UPF0236)//' <your_file> | awk '$9 < 1.0E-10'
```